# IOS: animation explosion cloud

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

I want insert into my app a particular animation, It must be as cloud-explosion...do you know when you leave a breakpoint in xcode? in this way...can you tell me how make it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by this piece of code:

```
NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil]; //this will be the frames of animation images in sequence.
 ringImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,600,600)];
 ringImage.animationImages = imageArray;
 ringImage.animationDuration = 1.5;//this the animating speed which you can modify
 ringImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 [ringImage startAnimating];//this method actually does the work of animating your frames.
```

This should get you going..:)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an animated `UIImageView`, with a set of images.